# Grails upgrade from 1.3 to 2.4

Tags: grails

I have a legacy grails app running on 1.3 on Java 6 with tomcat 6.
We need to upgrade to java 8 on tomcat 8. 
Is it possible to upgrade grails version from 1.3 to 2.4.5.
Lot of compilation issues and some of the holder classes are missing.
Please suggest.

Comment: Yes it's possible but it's a lot of work. You can't just change versions.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way we've found to upgrade between incompatible versions of Grails is to create a new application in the new version, and migrate the services/controllers/src directories into the new application.

You will need to keep in mind various changes (like the Holders classes you mentioned, which are now part of Holders in grails.util.Holders, iirc).  Also, you'll probably need to upgrade any plugins you use to newer 2.4.x-compatible versions as well (specifically spring-security, etc.)

It's not an easy task, but it can be done.  We've migrated from 1.x to 2.x before, and from 2.2 to 2.4, and we're currently migrating to 3.x.  BTW, since you're migrating, perhaps moving to 3.x would be a better move?

Good luck!