# Can i upgrade directly from Grails 2.x to Grails 4.x bypassing all median levels

Tags: grails, groovy

I am having an application build on grails 2.2.4. I need to update it to grails 4.0.8 Can i upgrade directly. As i checked from various sources, i need to jump first from 2.2.4 to 3.x then thereafter 3.x to 4.x. Please suggest me optimum way to do this upgrade.

Comment: How would we know what is optimal for your problem?

Comment: @cfrick I mean before upgrading median version, how can be jump to latest 4.x grails version as standard follows?

Comment: You can't.  There are no silver bullets. Follow the upgrading steps documented by the Grails maintaines **for your application**.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [other question about Grails upgrades](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47956719/grails-upgrade-from-1-3-to-2-4)

Major version upgrades in Grails are rarely trivial.  I'd suggest starting a new app in the target version, and migrating classes/functionalities.

Comment: Thanks @billjamesdev. I went through that link. What should be hierarchy median versions of grails that i should upgrade first before moving to upgrades to 4.x?

Comment: @billjamesdev In Genral, I think major version update involves breaking changes. In case of Grails framework, it really depends on underline libraries. I think that was one of reason where most users faced difficulties updating from Grails 2 to 3 because there were significant changes in the underline libraries. But, I think moving from Grails 3 to 4 is less complicated comparatively.

Comment: Thanks for research @Puneet Behl. So i am at this point by concluding that i can move directly from 2.x to 4.x while upgrading. Is this right @ Puneet Behl?

Comment: Yes, you should try to move from Grails 2 to 4.

Answer (score 0):

In Grails framework, the effort required to update your application depends on multiple factors, such as:

1. The standard practices. For instance, the persistence stuff in the Grails services instead of controller or domains itself.
2. The underline plugins your application depends on. You would need to update to the latest version of the plugin, or in some case find an alternative approaches as the plugin may longer be maintained, or there maybe better ways of doing it. For instance, we had some custom plugin for multi-tenancy back when I started with Grails, But now, GORM has great support for multi-tenancy.

I personally think you should directly jump from Grails 2 to Grails 4 by creating a new application, and then move your source code. But, first you need to identify all the variables such as plugins or libraries.